# Python pandas, nested loops, creating different lists from rows according to values in another row

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, loops

I've got an Excel file with 3 rows. The first row is the original text, in the second one there is the corrected version of the text and the third contains the starting point of each sentence.

It looks somewhat like this (sorry, I did not know how else to do this):

```
    A        B         C 
1  She                 x 
2  is
3  the 
4  besst     best
5  i         I         x
6  like
7  here      her
```

Some cells in column B are merged, but I took care of that and unmerged them. And only if something had to be corrected, there is a value in column, otherwise it is empty.
The end result I need is a file, in which the wrong and right sentence are complete and next to each other, like this:

```
She is the besst.    She is the best.
i like here.         I like her.
```

I tried to nest two loops within eachother, so if the cell in column is not empty, it will gather all values until the next cell in column c with a value (sentences so to speak).
And it works fine with the wrong sentences (the values from column A), but I cannot get it to work with column B.

```js
for i in range(len(df)):
  print(df.loc[i, "A"], df.loc[i, "B"])
  if i in value_in_columnB:
    print(df.loc[i, "B"])
    o = df.loc[i, "B"]
    correctsentence.append(o)
  else :
    print(df.loc[i, "A"])
    m = df.loc[i, "A"]
    correctsentence.append(m)

print(correctsentence)

correctsentence = [y for y in correctsentence if str(y) != 'nan']
print(correctsentence)
```

This code above works in that way that I can get all the correct sentences (mixture of columns A and B) in one long list, but not split up into individual sentences. The same is I can get it right, if it is only the first column, I just iterate over the rows and as soon as there is a value matched in the list of integers which show if there is an x in column C, it means that there is the start of a new sentence.

But somehow I cannot put both together. I just need to combine those two. What can I try? I've tried for and while loops and nothing seemed to help.

Comment: Hi, can you post a subset of the dataframe, and show the expected output. You can use this as a guide : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to at least make the desired output and example of the dataframe more readable because I could not find how to do it otherwise in that how to. does it suffice?

Answer (score 0):

So, when you input data looks like this:

```
a = 'She is the besst i like here'
b = ['', '', '', 'best', 'I', '', 'her']
c = ['x', '', '' , '', 'x', '', '']

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a.split(), 'B':b, 'C': c})
print(df)
```

---

```
       A     B  C
0    She        x
1     is         
2    the         
3  besst  best   
4      i     I  x
5   like         
6   here   her
```

---

Then this script:

```
df.loc[df['B'] == '', 'B'] = df[df['B'] == '']['A']
df.loc[df['C'] == 'x', 'C'] = 1
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C']).cumsum().ffill()

data = df.groupby('C')['A', 'B'].agg(list).to_dict('list')

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for incorrect, correct in zip(*data.values()):
        print('{}. {}.'.format(' '.join(incorrect), ' '.join(correct)), file=f_out)
```

Will create `file.txt` that contains:

```
She is the besst. She is the best.
i like here. I like her.
```

---

EDIT: Version with `NaN` values:

```
a = 'She is the besst i like here'
b = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'best', 'I', np.nan, 'her']
c = ['x', np.nan, np.nan , np.nan, 'x', np.nan, np.nan]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a.split(), 'B':b, 'C': c})

df.loc[df['B'].isna(), 'B'] = df[df['B'].isna()]['A']
df.loc[df['C'] == 'x', 'C'] = 1
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C']).cumsum().ffill()

data = df.groupby('C')['A', 'B'].agg(list).to_dict('list')

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for incorrect, correct in zip(*data.values()):
        print('{}. {}.'.format(' '.join(map(str, incorrect)), ' '.join(map(str, correct))), file=f_out)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really! But it still gives me the following error message with the last line:

print('{}. {}.'.format(' '.join(incorrect), ' '.join(correct)), file=f_out)

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Is there something wrong with my file or is it the code?

Comment: @emmafrank maybe you have some float data in columns `A` or `B`? You can try instead `print('{}. {}.'.format(' '.join(map(str, incorrect)), ' '.join(map(str, correct))), file=f_out)`

Comment: I fixed that problem by changing that line to: 

`print('{}. {}.'.format(' '.join([str(l) for l in incorrect]), ' '.join([str(a) for a in correct])), file=f_out)`!

But in the textfile the correct version does not have the values from the incorrect column in it. It looks like:
`nan nan nan best. I nan her.` Could you help again?

Comment: Oh well, I was writing my answer before I saw yours, yes, that fixed it :D

Comment: @emmafrank I added version that handles `NaN` values. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really! :) One last thing: in my original file I have some merged cells and solved the problem by remembering the index of those cells, this does not work work with your code (or I cannot implement it at least). So what I am getting now is something like:
**She is the best besst. I i like her here.**

Is there a quick fix for that? If not, I will still be forever grateful, thanks a lot!

Comment: @emmafrank That I'm not sure how to do it. The script I posted works with three columns - column `'A'` with incorrect sentence, column `'B'` with *only* corrections and column `'C'` with marker where the sentence begins.

Comment: Okay, still thanks a lot! One last question: I do that across multiple files, but it only saves the last (of course), what do I have to add so it appends the text in the txt file in the end?